# Capture current time in next empty cell

Tags: vba, excel

If I click on a button the time should be captured in Column E in the first empty cell starting at cell E5 and if that cell is not empty then it should automatically go to the next cell E6 then E7 ...

Here is the code that I use currently, but it doesn't work:

```
Sub Button4_Click()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect "pramtesh"
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect "pramtesh"

ActiveSheet.Value = Time()

ActiveSheet.Protect "pramtesh"
ActiveWorkbook.Protect "pramtesh"

Dim olApp As Object
   Dim olMailItm As Object
   Dim iCounter As Integer
   Dim Dest As Variant
   Dim SDest As String

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set olMailItm = olApp.CreateItem(0)
With olMailItm
       .To = ""
       .CC = ""
       .Subject = ""
       .Body = ""
       .Display
Application.Wait (Now)
Application.SendKeys "%s"
   End With
Set olMailItm = Nothing
   Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by this line `ActiveSheet.Value = Time()`

Comment: It means that in that particular sheet but at it does not capture time in the desired cell it captures time where the cursor is.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Sub Button4_Click()
    Dim iCounter%, Dest As Variant, SDest$, Lrow&
    Dim olApp As Object: Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim olMailItm As Object: Set olMailItm = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    'determinate the last used cell in column "E"
    Lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    'additional verification
    If Lrow < 5 Then 'if last used cell before [E5] then will be used [E5]
        Lrow = 5
    Else 'otherwise move to the next cell after last filled cell
        Lrow = Lrow + 1
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "pramtesh": ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect "pramtesh"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Lrow, "E").Value = Time() 'insert time into the cell
    ActiveSheet.Protect "pramtesh": ActiveWorkbook.Protect "pramtesh"
    With olMailItm
           .To = ""
           .CC = ""
           .Subject = ""
           .Body = ""
           .Display
    Application.Wait (Now)
    Application.SendKeys "%s"
    End With
    Set olMailItm = Nothing:  Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: HI,Thanks for the help however, this code is not working it is not capturing time in the desired cell but it is sending emails without capturing the time.

Comment: @Pramtesh, Oh, sorry, I did not understand a bit of your post, I thought that you need to insert into the cell [E5] the time of the message when it was sent, and if cell [E5] already has time then move to next cell. Could you specify, in which place (body, subject) the time shall be inserted?

Comment: @ Vasily, I am really sorry for not being clear earlier. Actually i work a call center and i have created a macro to capture the breaks of my team member. This means that when a person wants to go for a break he/she needs to click the button and the real time gets capture in the cell and then the email is sent. I want a Macro where the real time gets captured in the desired cell and then move to another cell if that cell contains text. For e.g if E5 contains time then if the button is clicked it should capture the real time in cell E6.

Comment: @Pramtesh, if I understand correctly, then take a look in my updated post. upon clicking on the button the current system time will be inserted into E5 or will moved to the next cell (in case when E5 will contain data, and so on)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the SendKeys method for sending an email programmatically. Instead, I'd suggest using the [Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866779(v=office.15).aspx) method of the MailItem class. See the [Using Automation to Send a Microsoft Outlook Message](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161088) article for a sample code.

```
 Sub SendMessage(DisplayMsg As Boolean, Optional AttachmentPath)
      Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
      Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
      Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
      Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachment

      ' Create the Outlook session.
      Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

      ' Create the message.
      Set objOutlookMsg  = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

      With objOutlookMsg
          ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
          Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("Nancy Davolio")
          objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

          ' Add the CC recipient(s) to the message.
          Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("Michael Suyama")
          objOutlookRecip.Type = olCC

         ' Add the BCC recipient(s) to the message.
          Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("Andrew Fuller")
          objOutlookRecip.Type = olBCC

         ' Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
         .Subject = "This is an Automation test with Microsoft Outlook"
         .Body = "This is the body of the message." &vbCrLf & vbCrLf
         .Importance = olImportanceHigh  'High importance

         ' Add attachments to the message.
         If Not IsMissing(AttachmentPath) Then
             Set objOutlookAttach = .Attachments.Add(AttachmentPath)
         End If

         ' Resolve each Recipient's name.
         For Each ObjOutlookRecip In .Recipients
             objOutlookRecip.Resolve
         Next

         ' Should we display the message before sending?
         If DisplayMsg Then
             .Display
         Else
             .Save
             .Send
         End If
      End With
      Set objOutlook = Nothing
  End Sub
```

Also you can read more about that in the [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) article.